# Опечатка при задавании вопроса в блоке "Больше полезных ссылок"

Tags: дефект, локализация

[image]
Должно быть "ПосЕтите", а не "ПосИтите".

Comment: Пускай все косяки перевода в одном месте будут.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica нашел еще дефект, который не указан в вопросе-дубликате. Мне отредактировать вопрос-дубликат, добавляя туда эту проблему?

Comment: Ага, лучше всё в одном месте собирать.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica да, что-то в упор вопроса не заметил.

Comment: Бывает, особенно под вечер)